# routing in MVC (html) at controller

Tags: html, model-view-controller, routes

```
public function clothdelete($id){

session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];


$cloth = new \App\Models\Owner();
$deleteclothes = $cloth->deleteclothes($id);
$clothes = $cloth->viewall($uid);

$data = ['clothes'=> $clothes,'success' => 'item successfully deleted!!'];
View::renderTemplate('Owner/index.html',$data);}
```

This is how I route in my system. There is no any problem in this code. The problem is when ever this controller is called, it deletes item(cloth with id) and route to Owner.index.html page with successful message.

So after I reach in index.html if I refresh this page the controller is called again and tries to perform delete action. When I refresh this page, the `clothdelete($id)` controller is called again and again.

How can I stop this? Using `header` might be an option but I don't know how to apply this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the delete (in your controller) a POST request vs. a GET request, then call delete within a form.  GET must be idempotent and safe.